# The driver executable does not exist: C:\geckodriver.exe issue in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

Please help me with this issue that is recurring every time I run my code.
I have extracted Geckodriver files in C Drive but when I run my code, the error that comes up is 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: C:\geckodriver.exe'.

**My code is given below:**

```
 package Basics;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Browserinvocation {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver.exe");

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();//FirefoxDriver class is used to implement methods present in Webdriver-Invocation of browser
driver.get("https://www.amazon.in/");// Get method to hit the url in browser 

}

}
```

**Error in console :**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver
>   executable does not exist: C:\geckodriver.exe     at
>   com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:534)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:136)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:131)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$100(GeckoDriverService.java:41)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(GeckoDriverService.java:141)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:339)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:158)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:98)
>     at Basics.Browserinvocation.main(Browserinvocation.java:13)

Comment: which is OS is yours?also mention jars and geckodriver version

Answer (score 1):

Above exception occurs whenever Precondition does not find path of relevant driver mentioned in System.setProperty() method by any reason like below:

1. if path mentioned have different/wrong/single slashes.
2. Driver file itself is not present at mentioned location.
3. If path is mentioned in properties file or config file with double quotes.

Just check once before execution.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the path to `geckodriver.exe` using `/` rather than `\\`. Change your line

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver.exe");
```

to the following

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:/geckodriver.exe");
```

Comment: adding some description to your answer would be nice. you should point out the mistake in the current code first of ann and then suggest the solution to fix it.

Comment: Still I am getting error - 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: C:\geckodriver.exe'   . I am running my automation code in Eclipse and somehow  the error that I have posted above is occurring again even after changing the path to forward slash                                                     (  'System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:/geckodriver.exe");'

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running at my side, might be you are not extracting the gecko driver.

Change the path and try it once, it should worked

Please let me know selenium jars version and your firefox browser version

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/Users/sankalp.gupta/Desktop/JAVASEL/geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.amazon.in");
System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
driver.close();
```

Comment: I changed the path of gecko driver and my code is working now . Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver.exe");
```

Here remove . in between gecko and driver

Answer (score 0):

Just download geckodriver.exe and move it to drive C: